# How do you do "Search, Sorting, Pagination"? in phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have customers contact list in show page.
and it is paginated.

I want to add search and sorting to this list.
I was looking into [rummage](https://hex.pm/packages/rummage_phoenix), but it seems not woring with phoenix 1.3. I get an error while mix deps.get that complaining requuire phoenix version.

And second options is [turbo_ecto](https://github.com/zven21/turbo_ecto). but I am having a hard time to understand and up and running.

I think search and sort is command functionality most people implement.
How do you do this? and how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before using any larger, complex, more confusing framework for sorting/searching, you can roll out your own solution.

#### Searching

Ecto provides [ilike/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#ilike/2) and [like/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#like/2). A simple full text solution could look like the following:

```
# In your Customer Controller
def index(conn, params = %{"name_search" => name_search}) do
  customers = Repo.all(from c in Customer,
    where: like(c.name, ^"%#{name_search}%"))

  # render customers
end
```

Note, `ilike/2` is only supported by postgresql. Also, this can lead to LIKE injection attacks since you let the user input wildcards. The input can be sanitized quite easily by following this guide tho: [LIKE Injection](https://githubengineering.com/like-injection/)

#### Sorting

A barebone sorting is also possible by utilizing [order_by/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#order_by/3)

```
# Extending your customer controller
# May want to transfer some of this logic to its own or context module

@sort_keys ~w(name email)

def index(conn, params = %{"name_search" => name_search, 
    "sort_key" => sort_key, "sort_type" => sort_type}) do

  sort_type = 
    case sort_type do
      "asc" -> :asc
      _ -> :desc
    end
  sort_key = 
    Enum.find(@sort_keys, "name", &(&1 == sort_key))
    |> String.to_atom


  customers = Repo.all(from c in Customer,
    where: like(c.name, ^"%#{name_search}%")),
    order_by: [{sort_type, sort_key}]

  # render customers
end
```

This solution allows for sorting by one key (which needs to be contained in `@sort_keys`) and either ascending or descending. This can easily be extended to support multiple sort keys at the same time, if required.

Both solutions surely can be abstracted at some point into their own modules/context modules.